# In SQL Developer, how to find distinct values of all columns of all tables in a database?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This was what i was trying

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
   sql_query VARCHAR2(32767);

BEGIN
    FOR t IN (SELECT  table_name, column_name FROM user_tab_columns) 
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_query := 'SELECT * FROM ' || t.table_name ;
    END LOOP;      
END;
```

Comment: Do you mean distinct NAMES of all columns of all tables? Also, in your attempt, you used the user_tab_columns table; that is only for one user's tables, but in your title you said all tables IN A DATABASE. Please clarify what you need, and why. (The **why** is often very helpful!)

Comment: you can just add **distinct** keyword in your query next to the **select** keyword . Eg. `select distinct column_name from table_name`

Comment: I wanted the distinct values in all columns of all tables. I used user_tab_columns so as to get the columns. It's not any work related, we just had an assignment and I was trying on this for a week, but unable to crack on how to get the column names. I am able to get the count in each table, but unable to go into the table to use distinct column values.

Comment: You **are** retrieving the column names, just use `select distinct '||t.column_name||' FROM ||'t.table_name` - But you need to store the result of that query somewhere. You can't just run it like that in a PL/SQL block

Answer (score 1):

This query gives you the number of distinct values per column (assuming that statistics are up to date).

```
select owner, table_name, column_name, num_distinct 
from all_tab_col_statistics
```

Maybe this would be enough.

If you need to have the distinct values, you have to modify the `sql_query` param in your script as follows:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_query := 'SELECT distinct '|| t.column_name || 
        ' FROM ' || t.table_name ;
```

Comment: Please mention that this is only exact if the `all_tab_col_statistics` is up-to-date.